# asynchronous function not executing sql CLR stored procedure

Tags: c#, .net, sql, asynchronous, sqlclr

I have a CLR stored procedure that i want to execute asynchronously from C#.

the code is as follow:

```
private delegate void GeneratePayrollDelegate(string payProcessID);

public void GeneratePayroll(string payProcessID)
    {
        GeneratePayrollDelegate del = new GeneratePayrollDelegate(GeneratePayrollAsync);
        del.BeginInvoke(payProcessID, null, null);
    }

public void GeneratePayrollAsync(string payProcessID)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(DLConnectionStringHelper.GetConnectionString() + "; async=true;"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("proc_GeneratePayroll", connection))
                {                        
                    cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { _Exceptions.ManageExceptions(ex); }
    }
```

This stored procedure executes successfully if it runs from sql.

When it executes from this code above, it gives no row inside the CLR stored procedure when trying to retrieve the row by the ID sent as parameter.

Need help!

Comment: In the CLR proc, one of the functions is taking some required information related to this payprocessID, it returns no rows.
when i try to retrieve row at postion 0, it gives range exception

Comment: So, it still executes successfully but you get unexpected results? It would be better to edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling   `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`; you should call `BeginExecuteReader` instead to get result as sample code can be like this

```
private void Asynchronous(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;
                try
                {
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand command =
                       asyncResult.AsyncState as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
                    reader = command.EndExecuteReader(asyncResult);
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {

                    }
                    reader.Close();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
}

public void GeneratePayrollAsync(string payProcessID)
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("proc_GeneratePayroll", connection))
            {
                command.CommandTimeout = 3600;
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                //Set Your stored procedure parameter here
                connection.Open();
                command.BeginExecuteReader(Asynchronous, command, CommandBehavior.Default);

            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {  }
}
```